# bots join when I swap teams

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, counter-strike-source

When I swap teams then the `bot_quota` of the server increases. How do I lock it so that it will stay constantly at 0 and bots will never be able to join?

Answer (score 1):

Try `bot_join_after_player 0` into the console.

You can also try `bot_kick_all` to quickly remove them.

The command `mp_limitteams 1` may also be helpful, it limits the players/bots on a team to the number you specify.